# jQuery appendTo function not working

Tags: jquery

Why is my function not working:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c5r6P/25/)

HTML:

```
<div class="cash">1234.00</div>
<div class="cash">123456.00</div>
<div id="total"></div>
```

JS:

```
function formatPrice(price) {
    return price.reverse().replace(/((?:\d{2})\d)/g, '$1 ').reverse();
}

// Need to extend String prototype for convinience
String.prototype.reverse = function() {
    return this.split('').reverse().join('');
}

$('.cash').each(function(){
    $(this).html().formatPrice().appendTo('body');
});
```

I tried this as well, no luck:

```
$('.cash').each(function(){
    $(this).html() = i;
    formatPrice(i).appendTo('body');
});
```

---

Even whenstripping it down to a basic function, it still does not append my stuff...Am I losing my mojo?

```
$('.cash').each(function(){
    $(this).html().appendTo('body');
});
```

Thanks

UPDATE: The function is just suppose to do this:

formatPrice('1234.00')  //convert to "1 234.00"
formatPrice('123456.00') //convert to "123 456.00"

Comment: What's it supposed to do?

Comment: Console is your friend. `Uncaught TypeError: Object 1234.00 has no method 'formatPrice'`

Comment: It is just suppose to format my numbers - see update:

Comment: Where does the `formatPrice` function come from?

Comment: don't be a fool, wrap your tool

Comment: Look at your errors. `$(this).html().formatPrice()` would throw one.

Comment: `formatPrice` is returning a string, not the `$(this)` jQuery object... also, I think the code should be replacing the contents of `.cash`, not appending it to the body.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make your example working, you should fix this part of code:

```
$('.cash').each(function(){
    $('body').append(formatPrice($(this).html()));
});
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c5r6P/28/)

You cannot run `html().formatPrice()`, because `formatPrice()` in your case is standalone function, but not a method of a string object.

If you want to replace the text inside `div.cash`, please use this code:

```
$('.cash').each(function(){
    $(this).html(formatPrice($(this).html()));
});
```

Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c5r6P/32/)

If you want to be able to use `formatPrice()` for any string, please do the following:

```
String.prototype.formatPrice = function() {
    return this.reverse().replace(/((?:\d{2})\d)/g, '$1 ').reverse();
}

$('.cash').each(function(){
    $(this).html(function(i, h) { return h.formatPrice() });
});
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c5r6P/34/)

So, just select the option you like and use it.

Comment: I know the OP did this, but I think the code should be replacing the contents of `.cash`, not appending it to the `body`.

Comment: Cool ;)... also it might be more efficient to use the [HTML function](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) : `$(this).html(function(i,h){ return formatPrice(h); });`

Comment: @Mottie, added your hint to last example. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the last fiddle as well netme, appreciate

Answer (score 4):

`$(this).html()` returns the html in text, not a jQuery object that contains the `appendTo` function.

You can do:

```
$($(this).html()).appendTo('body');
```

Btw you shouldn't "pick up html" and assume that it is safe to pass it to your `formatPrice` function.

Do like this, it is cleaner:

```
<div class="cash" data-cash="1234.00">1234.00</div>

$('body').append(formatPrice($(this).attr("data-cash")));
```

Comment: Or, in this case, `$(formatPrice($(this).html())).appendTo('body')`.